# Using Sharepoint 2010 how can I keep all the items in a choice field after saving the listitem

Tags: list-item

I have a list that contains a choice field set as a checkbox. It contains a number of items that need a process applied to them. When the process is complete for an item, it is checked. When the List-item is saved and reopened for further work, only the checked items are in the choice field. I want to be able to edit the list-item and continue checking the choice field until I have checked all the choices. Also, is it possible to generate a %Complete field to show status of the work?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. When I open the List-item it only displays the selected choices, however when I edit the List-Item, all the choices are still there. Thanks...